# Workflow Flow trigger issue

Tags: workflow, flow, visual-workflow

I have a workflow rule with Flow trigger to perform some action but it is working fine in my sandbox system but it is not working in production, In debug logs I am getting

Error: Could not evaluate formula for value passed to Flow (Flow Name).

I found some KI : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008aYDAAY but don't it is related to mine.

My workflow rule is on Opportunity.

Please suggest why this error comes or this is generic like other flow errors.

Comment: The link to the article you posted has to do with updating child records. Is your Flow updating child records? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I am just creating new Opportunity from an old Opp and copying products as well then I am seeing this error

Comment: Well without seeing more, I'm guessing you have a formula in your flow?  Also I'm assuming you're saving the new Opp ID to pass to the products2 create function?